# Rails send mail with gmail development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendmail

I didn't figure out how I send mail from gmail in development environment.It didn't send email. I didn't understand the rails guide, and also I wonder if the production env is the same ?

> config/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'something.com' } 
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
port:                 587,
domain:               'mail.google.com',
user_name:            'myusername@gmail.com',
password:             'mypassword',
authentication:       'plain',
enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

> mailer/user_mailer.rb

```
 default :from => 'something.com'

 def welcome_email(user)
   @user = user
   @url  = 'http://something.com'
   mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome')
 end
```

### edit

> where I call, in users create method,

```
UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_now
```

Comment: Where are you calling the mailer from?

Comment: I will update for it

Comment: So no errors?  What is in the log?

Comment: Update your error log here. Thanks

Comment: No errors, I m creating the user succesfully, but mail is not sending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Try this in `development.rb` It will either send mail or raise delivery error in console.

Comment: I m looking for in a console where I run the server

Comment: try this `UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_now!`

Comment: I got the error this time, **No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25**

Comment: change your domain option in smtp_settings as
`domain: "gmail.com"`
it will work for you.

Comment: Try with restarting the server. Thanks

Comment: Check your username or password. Error should change now.

Comment: Sorry I will restart the server now and I got this error, **534-5.7.9 Application-specific password required. Learn more at**

Comment: Now your code is right. Login into your google account and disable 2 factor authentication. After that it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can call your mailer methods in two way to send email,

1. In `UsersController`'s `create` action

   ```
   def create
       #your codes and logics to save user...
       UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_now
       #your codes goes here ...  
   end
   ```
2. In `User` model `after_create` callback

   ```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      after_create :send_email

      def send_email
         UserMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver_now
      end  
    end
   ```

I would prefer second one for sending email, use model callback rather in controller.

Comment: second one will give an error, **undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass**

Comment: Edited @use was getting nil, I copied you code and forgot to replace `@user` in model, because it's not available here, `self` send and user object and it should have `email`. Try now.

Comment: nothing happen but when ı try the `deliver.now!` , I got the error **No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25**

Comment: Your question was from where you should send email, right ? this the way to send email. now the problem is in you `smtp` that not allow to receive email. Try another port in your configuration like  465 and 25, check which one work.

Comment: I restart the server and the problem is not the same now, **534-5.7.9 Application-specific password required. Learn more at**

Comment: This problem is for your credentials, you can try with new email.